# Imac Whistling noise

Tags: imac

My computer has this annoying whistle sound that goes and comes back.  Does someone have an idea what it might be?  Do I need to take it to the apple shop?

2.93 GHz Intel Core i7
12 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
ATI Radeon HD 5750 1024 MB
OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)

Comment: Does the noise happen more often while the iMac is under heavy CPU load, rendering graphics / playing games etc?  Do you have any external speakers plugged in, does the sound definitely come from the internal speakers, or do you think it's fan noise?  Have you tried putting the iMac onto a different AC outlet/UPS/surge protector?

Comment: @da4 it has happens all the time. Apple decided to replace the machine after over a year of me using it so I assume its something big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motherboard (PRAM) needed resetting by turning off the computer and then restarting while pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Opt</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>. The noise is gone.